# Starting up dijits in templates

Tags: javascript, templates, dojo

I have created a new dijit, which contains some standard dijits in the template. It seems that the dijits in the template are not started. What is the best way to do this? Also, if I have committed any other errors, please pick me up on them, as I last worked with Dojo about 3 years ago....

**Update** I am using Dojo 1.8 and rely on modules being auto-required. I only have a limited ability to change the environment I am working with as this is a subset of a larger project.

**Update 2** Question has been answered below, but you're welcome to comment on any issue you spot with my template... :-)

```
define([
"dojo/_base/declare",
"dijit/_WidgetBase", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin", 
"dojo/text!my/templates/CheckDate.html"
], function(declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, template){
    var x = declare("my.CheckDate", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
        templateString: template,
    });
    return x;
});
```

Template:

```
<div class="row checkDate">
<div class="col paddingRightDiv third">
    <input type="checkbox" id="${name}_Check" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/CheckBox" />
    <label for="${name}_Check">${label}</label>
</div>
<div class="col paddingRightDiv half whenbox">
    <label for="${name}_Date">When might this be?</label>
    <input type="text" id="${name}_Date" name="${name}_Date" maxlength="6" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get Dijits going in your template, you need to add `dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin`

The dijit code now looks like this, demonstrating a simple event handler..

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase", 
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
    "dojo/text!my/templates/CheckDate.html"
], function(declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, template){
    var x = declare("my.CheckDate", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
    templateString: template,
    showDate: function(e) {
        var attr = e ? "block" : "none";
        var id = this.when.id;
        dojo.style(id, "display", attr);            
    },
    });
return x;
});
```

The template code has been simplified a little,using the `${id]` and `connectNode`:

```
<div class="row checkDate">
<div class="col paddingRightDiv third">
    <input type="checkbox" id="${id}_Check" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/CheckBox" 
        data-dojo-attach-point="check" data-dojo-attach-event="onChange: showDate"/>
    <label for="${id}_Check" data-dojo-attach-point='containerNode'></label>
</div>
<div class="col paddingRightDiv half whenbox" id="${id}_When" data-dojo-attach-point="when" >
    <label for="${id}_Date">What Date?</label>
    <input type="text" class="miniTextBox" id="${id}_Date" name="${id}_Date" maxlength="5" 
           data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" promptMessage="Example: 10/14" data-dojo-props="pattern:'^[01]\\d\\/\\d\\d'" />
</div>
```

Comment: I'd like to add one more trick if you're already using `_WidgetsInTemplateMixin`. By setting the not-so-documented `contextRequire` property, you can enable *relative* references to subwidgets in your template. (e.g. `data-dojo-type="../myotherstuff/CustomWidget"`) You can see a code sample in [Dojo ticket #16112](https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/16112) that shows how you pass `require` through so that it has the relative context.

Comment: Thankyou. I'm actually using relative references, but changed the example to show my actual problem. The only other problem I have at the moment is that I'm having trouble using data-dojo-attach-event to pick up the onclick event from the checkbox in the example above.

Comment: yep, that was due to fixing another issue

Answer (score 1):

Can the problem be solved with a simple onClick in the HTML?

Like :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="${name}_Check" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/CheckBox" onClick="javascript:callMyFunction();" />
```

Otherway you could try to connect the Checkbox to an Event like:

```
on("${name}_Check","click",function(){....});
```

or

```
on("${name}_Check","click",callMyFunction);
```

**Update 1:**

If u want to load it at the start u can initialize it like this:

```
/**************Init-Bereich***************************/
var AnlagenStore;
var queryTaskAnlagenNummern, queryallAnlagenNummern;

dojo.ready(initKielAnlagenNummernSuchen);
function initKielAnlagenNummernSuchen(){

    queryTaskAnlagenNummern = new esri.tasks.QueryTask(restServicesLocation + NameSearchService + "/MapServer/23");

    queryallAnlagenNummern = new esri.tasks.Query();
    queryallAnlagenNummern.returnGeometry = true;
    queryallAnlagenNummern.outFields = ["ANLAGE"];

    require(["dojo/keys","dojo/dom","dojo/on"], function(keys, dom, on){
        on(dojo.byId("selectAnlagenNummer"), "keypress", function(evt){
            var charOrCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
            if (charOrCode == keys.ENTER) {
                zoomToAnlage();
            }
        });
    });

}
/**************Init-Bereich-ENDE***************************/
```

I load this one at the top of the called Javascript-File to catch up the onkeypress event. The dojo ready garants you that dojo and all functionalitys are allready loaded

Hope this might help.

Regards, Miriam

Comment: It could, but I'm trying to keep Javascript functionality and HTML separate.

Comment: Please look above - i updated my post to show how u can solve this with pure javascript

Answer (score 0):

My first advise is that it must be

```
require([....,...],function(...){});
```

and not define.

As reference here's a part of the doje Template-Example:

```
require([
 "dojo/_base/declare",
 "dijit/_WidgetBase",
 "dijit/_OnClickDijitMixin",
 "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
 "dojo/text!./templates/SomeWidget.html"
  ],
   function(declare, _WidgetBase, _OnClickDijitMixin, _TemplatedMixin, template) {

    declare("example.SomeWidget", [_WidgetBase, _OnClickDijitMixin, _TemplatedMixin], {
    templateString: template
    //  your custom code goes here
    });

});
```

and here's the link for it : http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/templated/

Maybe it's enough to change define into require to load the widgets correct.

Regards, Miriam

Comment: Nope, require produces a proto not defined error. Maybe if you know why that occurs.... :-). It is possible that it is due to the fact I am relying on AMD module autoloading. I followed that example and had to change require to define to get it to work in the first place.

Comment: Can you tell more about the errors you get? Is the path to your Template correct? check this : "dojo/text!./my/templates/CheckDate.html"

Comment: Hm, i'm stuck here. Which Version of dojo do u use? Maybe it is because your actual Version of dojo ( the example is written in 1.7 ) is too old for "require". We are working with 1.8

Comment: I've just found the solution, you need a dijit/WidgetsInTemplateMixin in the mix - it was at the bottom of the page you referred to. Thanks for your help - I'll put a detailed answer below

Comment: Thanks, quite often I come up with the answer to my own problems simply by talking them through

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use `define` here. It *might* be helpful to include a namespace/classname in the call to `declare`, but switching from `define` to `require` won't fix anything.